# Laravel havingRaw works with get() but not with count()

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've got a query which includes some raw parts and looks similar to next one:

```
 $bills = Bill::leftJoin('important_dates', 'important_dates.id', '=', 'bills.important_date_id')
    ->selectRaw("IF(bills.credit_card_id IS NULL AND important_dates.sent_at IS NOT NULL, important_dates.sent_at, bills.date) AS 'constructed_date'")
    ->havingRaw('constructed_date BETWEEN \''.$data_model['date_from'].'\' AND \''.$data_model['date_to'].'\'');
```

If I use `$bills->get()` it works perfectly fine, returning what it is supposed to. But if I use `$bills->count()` an error is thrown with message `Unknown column 'constructed_date' in 'having clause'`. Does that mean that I mustn't have `having` clause when using `->count()` function?

The SQL query looks like this:

```
select IF(bills.credit_card_id IS NULL AND important_dates.sent_at IS NOT NULL, important_dates.sent_at, bills.date) AS 'constructed_date' 
from bills 
left join important_dates on important_dates.id = bills.recipient_batch_id 
having constructed_date BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2020-02-29' 
order by constructed_date asc
```

Comment: Kindly show the raw SQL query. I think the issue is ALIAS is not allowed in the HAVING clause, GROUP BY and WHERE clause. only allowed in ORDER BY.

Comment: Here, I have added SQL. It works, it retrieves data in MySql  and in Laravel also (when using `get()`). It just doesn't work with `count()`

Comment: Do not insert strings into your query like this. It's very dangerous. Use placeholders and parameters as in the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#aggregates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you using `count()`, laravel will use `SELECT COUNT(*)` 
to cover

```sql
select IF(bills.credit_card_id IS NULL AND important_dates.sent_at IS NOT NULL, important_dates.sent_at, bills.date) AS 'constructed_date'
```

after that, mysql cannot find the `constructed_date`, so the error occurs.

You can use `whereBetween` instead of `havingRaw`, it can prevent SQL-injection:

```php
->whereBetween(DB::raw('IF(bills.credit_card_id IS NULL AND important_dates.sent_at IS NOT NULL, important_dates.sent_at, bills.date)'), array($data_model['date_from'], $data_model['date_to']))
```

So this time you can use `count()`, because when it change `select count(*)`, there is no need to use `constructed_date`.

Comment: Will try it right now, but I just thought that I can escape using same condition multiple times in same query by declaring and alias (`constructed_date`). I will asign it as a string to a variable outside query and use it on those two spots

Comment: But what if I want to order by this column also? Actually by that condition

Comment: @johnnybegood then you still need to use orderBy(DB::raw("..."))

Comment: Actually not! If you use alias `as SOME_NAME` you maybe can't use that alias in `whereBetween` clause, but you can use it in `orderBy()`. But thank you, you have brought me to this solution!

Comment: @johnnybegood yes. but if you use `count`, the alias name will be cover, so you need to redeclare it.

Comment: @johnnybegood sorry, you are right, if you use` orderBy()`, you don't use `count`, you can use alias.

Comment: `havingRaw` can prevent injection, if used properly. e.g. `havingRaw("date between ? and ?", [$date1, $date2])` https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#aggregates

Comment: @miken32 That was initial problem. I couldn't use `havingRaw` since I was using alias in that clause and it resulted in throwing error `Unknown column` when I use it with `count()` function (worked perfectly fine with `get()`). I don't have column `date` in any of the tables, it is being created through that `IF` condition I have mentioned in my question.